# PHP access XML node element

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to edit some XML with PHP. Currently the XML looking something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Main Title</title>
    <link>http://exmaple.com</link>
    <description> blahblahblah </description>
    <language>en</language>
    <item>
      <title>Tite1</title>
      <link>http://www.example.com (THIS IS WHAT I WANT)</link>
      <description>blah blah blah</description>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I've tried to access the 2nd level link but my code only changes the first Link node value. Here is the code:

```
       $xml->load('http://www.google.com/doodles/doodles.xml');
    $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $secondlvl = $element->getElementsByTagName('item')->item(0);
    $2ndlevellinknode = $element->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);
    $2ndlevellinknode->nodeValue = $newvalue;
```

Any suggestions? Also is it possible to use this line of code in a for loop like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
    $secondlvl = $element->getElementsByTagName('item')->item(0);
    $2ndlevellinknode = $element->getElementsByTagName('link')->item($i);
    $2ndlevellinknode->nodeValue = $newvalue;
}
```

Comment: I personally find [PHP's SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) much easier to work with.

Comment: $2ndlevellinknode = $secondlvl->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0); // not $element->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);

Comment: Can someone give an example of doing this with SimpleXML?

Comment: I can cook up something with DomDocument. What do you want to replace it to?

Comment: I was trying to replace the second level link node.

Comment: Replace it with what? Im writing it now

Comment: Anything - I was going to be putting a different link in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should give you an idea.

```
$f = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
print $f->channel->title . "\n";
print $f->channel->link . "\n";
print $f->channel->description . "\n";
foreach($f->channel->item as $item) {
  print $item->title . "\n";
}
```